# What will be EOF here in the below code?

Tags: c, character, ascii, eof, getchar

I was reading the C programming language book and in the given below code I am not quite getting how will we be getting an EOF here? And also I don't exactly get what is an EOF? is it a character, integer or a condition? If it is a condition then please explain. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
  printf("%d", c != EOF);
  putchar(c);
}
printf("\n%d\n", c != EOF);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getchar` function can return any possible character that can be represented on your system, *plus* one more, additional, special, "out-of-band" return value indicating that there are no more characters to be returned.  This value is referred to by the symbolic macro identifier `EOF`.  Somewhere behind `<stdio.h>` there is typically a definition like

```
#define EOF (-1)
```

The value isn't necessarily -1, but that will serve our purposes.  (We don't have to know or care what the actual value is, because we always refer to `EOF`, insulating us from the actual value.)

Whatever value `EOF` has, it's guaranteed not to be the same as any actual character.  So if `getchar` returns a value other than `EOF`, it's an actual character that has been read.  But if it returns `EOF`, that's the indication that the input stream has reached end-of-file, that there are no more characters to be read.

So `EOF` is most definitely *not* a character.  It is an integer, with a value different than any `char`.  I wouldn't call it a "condition", although it you test for it, using code like

```
if(c == EOF)
```

or

```
if(c != EOF)
```

I would say that those expressions `c == EOF` and `c != EOF` are conditions.

It's especially confusing because typically there's a special character you can type on the keyboard to generate an end-of-file indication.  On Windows it's control-Z; on Unix and other systems it's control-D.  But this does *not* mean that `EOF` is control-Z on a Windows system or that it's control-D on a Unix system.  Those characters are handled by the terminal driver and translated into an indication that, after several additional levels of handling and interpretation, causes `getchar` to return `EOF`.  But one way to prove that `EOF` is *not* control-Z or control-D is to observe that when you're using `getchar` or `getc` to read from a file, you get an `EOF` indication at end-of-file even though there's no one typing control characters at a keyboard in that case.

Finally, this discussion reminds us of the importance of using `int` variables to carry the values returned by `getchar`.  The code you cited correctly declared

```
int c;
```

and then used the variable `c` to hold the values returned by `getchar`.  Why use an `int` here?  Since `getchar` returns characters, and since `c` is a character, wouldn't it make more sense to declare

```
char c;
```

That  *seems* like it makes sense, but it's actually quite wrong.  Type `char` can hold any character the system can represent.  But remember, `getchar` can return any character value, *plus* the `EOF` value.  If you assign `getchar`'s return value to a variable of type `char`, you end up "scraping off" the EOF indication, by inadvertently mapping it to an actual character value.  What happens next is either that you map an actual character (usually ÿ) to `EOF` and mistakenly stop reading when you read one, or that you map `EOF` to an actual character and so never detect it and so go into an infinite loop instead of stopping at end-of-file.

Comment: Thank you great explanation, that did clear much of my confusions. Although how will I get EOF in the above code?

Comment: @gunjanpatait When you run the program, try typing "A B C <Return> <Control-Z> <Return>" on a Windows system, or  "A B C <Return> <Control-D>" on a Unix, Linux, or Mac system.

Answer (score 2):

EOF means end of file. When you read a input stream (file, keyboard, etc) EOF is returned when the stream is over . EOF is commonly represented by the int -1

Answer (score -1):

EOF is Condition. Now Let's Take An Example.
You have 1 .txt file in which you have written 50 lines but you doesn't know that how many characters are there in that .txt file. Now you want to print all character from that .txt file to your c language program but still you doesn't know how many characters are there. for that you have to use EOF (Means End OF File) which is being condition of your for loop or while loop. and this loop will be continued to the last character of your .txt file.